# Why doesn't TypeScript check for extraneous properties in objects returned from a function?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the Type `SomeType`

```
export type SomeType = {
    name:string
}
```

Now I have two functions :

```
const handle = (c:SomeType) => {

}

const handle2 = (func: () => SomeType) => {

}
```

I understand why this throws a type checking error ('Hello does not exist in type SomeType'):

```
handle({
    name:'',
    hello:'world'
})
```

Although, if I call `handle2` :

```
handle2(() => ({           
    name:'',
    hello:'world'
 }))
```

This should fail for the exact same reason but it doesn't. Why ?

Comment: If you explicitly type the arrow function's return value, it will. But otherwise the compiler just checks that it's _compatible_.

Comment: But TypeScript knows that the function I give **must** return a `SomeType`. Explicitly typing the arrow function makes it redundant.

Comment: [^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77397244/why-doesnt-typescript-check-for-extraneous-properties-in-objects-returned-from?noredirect=1#comment136445570_77397244) Re that, here's an example of doing that: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKEC2wAqzUC8cA3gFBwVwB2AhtgFxwDOMUAllQOYDcpAvr1IBjCFRZwAFjSoATADaE4ACiGMM2PCgCUcAgD4S5SgHpjcAHSX+gkWPhTZCgEy7lAMwCuVVcp370WLj4fgZklHCmFlYCpKQO8sBKYZS0DHAAROkANEYUEsBychCM6QDu0HIy2fxagvHOSrm+aoGahAZJTeGpwCXV4eH5hcUZ5VCV-ZR8WqS1QA Since the returned object literal is directly assigned to `SomeType`, TypeScript catches it.

Comment: @ArthurAttout - It must return a `SomeType` *or a subtype of it*. Subtypes are perfectly valid. Excess property checks are a pragmatic check to help when doing direct assignments purely because they're probably errors. But assigning subtype instances to supertype variable (etc.) is a valid operation. More in [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#excess-property-checks).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I really don't understand why I would not want to directly assign a subtype of `SomeType` directly when calling `handle`. I don't see why the return value from a function would not undergo the same restrictions.

Comment: Even the doc seems vague on this. I don't understand if it is a technical limitation or an intentional design.

Comment: @ArthurAttout - It's intentional design. Let's start here: `a = b` is valid if the type of `b` is the same as `a` or a *subtype* of it. That's important because it's often appropriate -- think `appendNode` in the DOM, which doesn't *only* work with `Node` instances, but with anything that's a subtype of `Node` (like `Element`, `HTMLElement`, `HTMLInputElement`, ...). `{name: string; hello: string; }` is a subtype of `{name: string; }` (it satisifies the type by having a string `name`). So in the general case, it's not useful to flag up excess properties because in the general case, we...

Comment: ...want to allow them. **But**, if you do `a: SomeType = (object literal)` or an analog of it (like `return (object literal)` in an explicitly-typed function) and the object literal has properties the type doesn't have, the TypeScript team figure that's probably a coding error, so they offer excess property checks **only** in that situation, as a pragmatic lint-style check. But it's really narrowly focussed, because in the general case we want to allow assigning subtypes.